# Turn Off XAML error underlining

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

This is a simple issue, and I hope someone can help

For reasons I don't think I need to explain, my XAML thinks it has some errors in it in the Visual Studio code editor (which shows as wavy blue underlines across most of my XAML).

Does anyone know how to turn this underlining off in Visual Studio 2012 ?

It's incredibly annoying, and makes my XAML hard to read

Thanks

Comment: I agree, it is very annoying that you can't temporarily turn off xaml error underlining. A lot of times you get false positive errors ... sometimes you just want to read xaml. It is an utter fail not to be able to turn it off. #fail

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest setting the editor for .xaml-files manually.

Go into

> Tools->Options->Text Editor->File Extension

Write **xaml** in the *Extension* field and choose **XML (Text) Editor** from the *Editor* drop down and then click *Add*.

Your XAML files should now open as ordinary XML files, without error underlining.

You will probably loose a lot of the nice to have features of the XAML editor, but as far as I know (I've struggled a bit with this myself) it is the only way.

Comment: There has to be another way. This was nice, but I like Intellisense to be available to me.

Answer (score 3):

Found this on MSDN.  There is a specific setting to disable this.

> Open the Options dialog by selecting Tools > Options, and then select
> Text Editor > XAML > Miscellaneous.
>
> Uncheck the Show errors detected
> by the XAML designer check box.

[Article from MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/designers/xaml-errors-warnings?view=vs-2017)

Answer (score 1):

The only decent fix for this silly bug that I can find is right click on the xaml and click open with. Select source code editor (without *with encoding*). Not a great fix when you consider it gets rid of important errors. But it should help you read it better for the most part.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to hide the `SquiggleShape` by making the surrounding adornment layer hidden or collapsed using the Snoop tool.

To achieve this, the Snoop crosshair tool has to be dragged on the editor window with shift and ctrl keys pressed (keep them pressed a while when releasing mouse button). You should end on some `Canvas` (with the editor window highlighted), and below there is some `ViewStack`. Inside, there are some `AdornmentLayer`, one of which contains multiple `SquiggleShape`. In the properties section on the right side of the Snoop window, scroll to the `Visibility` row and select the value `Hidden` or `Collapsed`. Now, the squiggle lines are not visible any more.

This involves some manual work, but as long as the file stays open, the squiggle lines are hidden. In principle, it should be possible to write an extension which hides the lines automatically. However, at the moment I don't find the time to do this...

Comment: Love that you used Snoop for this. Love it.

Answer (score 0):

Another Option for this is to change the color of the line under: Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors. Change it to the same as the background.

[image: Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors]

It will turn it off in all other editors also though.